# Form.show() starting from event in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, invoke

I have a Class that trigger an event in a Form project.
The method in the class that trigger the event is running in separate thread.
The question is how can I load the form from the main thread (UI thread)

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
        static public Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cl1.event1 += new Class1.del(CreateForm);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl1.Almog();
        }

        static public void CreateForm()
        {
            //Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
        }
    }
} 

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public event del event1;
        public delegate void del();

        public void Almog ()
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(Print);
            t1.Name="class1";
            t1.Start();
        }
        public void Print ()
        {
            event1();
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in the loop");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the Form using MethodInvoker. like this...

```
           static public void CreateForm()
            {
              Form2 f2 = new Form2();
              f2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
              {

                    f2.Show();
              }));
            }
```

Comment: This won't compile. Using `this` in a static method is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an exception **Cross-thread operation not valid** if you call one form from another. For this you need to invoke the method call.

```
static public void CreateForm()
{
   f2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate(){ f2.Show();}));
}
```

Also, read this for further clarification:

> [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if you need to invoke the method call.

```
static public void CreateForm() {
    Action action = () => { f2.Show(); };
    if (f2.InvokeRequired) {
        f2.Invoke(action);
    } else {
        action();
    }
}
```